# What is the definition of "snap" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english

In [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/10/04/travel/fall-foliage-united-states-timing.html) headline:

> How to Time Your Leaf-Peeping Trip This Fall
>
> The symphony of colors that accompanies the arrival of a snap in the air is playing out differently in 2022.

What is this "snap" the author is talking about?

Comment: @TonyK It's a reasonably common [US/Canadian term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf_peeping) – to my British eyes it does sound very strange and it doesn't align with the usage of 'peeping' as a standalone word, but that's the nature of language. It's like complaining that the use of 'rolling' in 'rickrolling' is illiterate.

Comment: @dbmag9: Thank you for that! I have learnt something today.

Comment: @TonyK From my experience, it's a pretty regional term, confined to areas where fall foliage is worth traveling to see.  I lived in several places in the US & Canada and never heard the term;  only when I moved to my current home in New England (where the fall colors are quite nice) did I learn the term.

Answer (score 11):

We usually explicitly include the adjective in...

> [***a cold snap***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cold-snap).
> a short period of cold weather

Note that there's no such thing as a ***hot / dry / wet / windy snap***. Idiomatically, ***snaps*** are only ever ***cold***.

---

For reasons that aren't easy to spell out, OP's cited usage is only really idiomatic because of ***in the air*** (most Anglophones would do a double-take if neither ***cold*** nor ***in the air*** was present here). I think maybe that's because the ***snap = short period** [of weather]* meaning is sufficiently rare that it needs to be explicitly clarified somehow.

---

EDIT: When I first wrote this answer, the only relevant definition I could find in generally accessible online sources was the one from Cambridge Dictionary above (*explicitly* defining just the specific collocation ***cold** snap*). I now see that the full (subscription-only) Oxford English Dictionary has two subcategories of their definition 7...

> **snap**  (Originally U.S.)
> **7a** *A brief and sudden spell of a particular type of weather, esp. **cold weather***.
> **7b** (With modifying word)
> *A brief and sudden spell of a particular type of weather; esp. a **sharp and sudden frost**; a short spell of cold weather (see also **cold snap** noun)*.

Giving the lie to my "no such thing..." assertion in the initial text, the full OED includes cited examples of ***black, cool, bitter, wet, hot*** and ***winter snaps***. But I *still* think many native speakers would find several of those "odd" - they're certainly not *common* usages.

Comment: In the UK we can talk of  'a nip in the air', but not, I think, a 'snap in the air'

Comment: @FumbleFingers, are you then saying that it would be same as: "The symphony of colors that accompanies the arrival of [THIS SHORT PERIOD OF WEATHER]  is playing out differently in 2022. Please Note that I've removed "in the air" in the rewriting.

Comment: Not where I live! Or within the context of BBC weathermen, who have definitely referred to the current ***cold snap*** within the last few days. I don't recall them talking about there being a nip in the air though (bit "folksy", that! :)

Comment: @Lynerapintcho: What I meant was that if the text didn't include either "cold" or "in the air" it would probably be seen as "weird" (and/or not understood) by many if not most native speakers. This use of ***snap*** (always ***cold***) is a bit like the way all dudgeon is high, all petrels are stormy, and all shift is short.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey:  "Snap in the air" is unidiomatic to my US ears as well, though understandable.  "Nip in the air" or "chill in the air" would be more common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - warm snaps seem to exist for [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/metro/daily/graphics/meWarm_010705.html), the [Irish Mirror](https://www.irishmirror.ie/news/irish-news/ireland-weather-met-eireann-confirm-26543080), [National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/culture/article/120620-green-antarctica-trees-global-warming-science-ancient), and [Drapers Online (UK)](https://www.drapersonline.com/news/nervous-retailers-shrink-orders-after-warm-snap) among others. I confess I was surprised.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I think I may have misunderstood your first comment. Apart from the fact that I feel *a **nip** in the air* is rather more informal than *a cold **snap*** (cf *Wear a scarf - it's **a bit nippy** out[side]*), I don't really have an opinion as to whether one is more common than the other. But they're certainly ***used*** differently. The two standard versions are *There's **a cold snap** coming* and *There's **a nip in the air*** - I would never expect *There's **a cold nip** coming* or *There's **a snap in the air***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - you understood my first comment perfectly. I, too, would never expect a cold nip or a snap in the air. I was reacting to your comment that snaps are always cold. I thought so, as well, but warm ones do seem to be a thing now.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: All ***shrift*** (not *shift*) is ***short***, all ***snaps*** are ***cold***, and all ***nips*** are ***in the air***. Your links notwithstanding, I'm gratified to see [*Ngrams not found: **had a warm snap***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+a+cold+snap%2Chad+a+warm+snap&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20a%20cold%20snap%3B%2Cc0)